# python3 requests return 400 Bad Request

Tags: python, json, curl, python-requests

Using curl I get the hash

```
$ curl "http://127.0.0.1:8002/hash/" -X POST -d 'data={"key":"value"}'
{
  "hash": "9724c1e20e6e3e4d7f57ed25f9d4efb006e508590d528c90da597f6a775c13e5"
}
```

Using Python requests return 400

```
import json
import requests
r = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8002/hash/', data = 'data={"key":"value"}', allow_redirects=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try passing it in with just `{"key":"value"}` as your data.

So that would be:

```
r = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8002/hash/', data = '{"key":"value"}', allow_redirects=False)
```

requests can also accept a dictionary object or a list of tuples as it's data argument, which is probably easier and more intuitive than directly entering a string.  Also note that you can work with a dictionary and turn it into a json string with `json.dumps`.

Comment: r = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8002/hash/', '{"key":"value"}', allow_redirects=False) - return same result

Comment: what you wrote there is different -- in your example you specified data twice.  specify data as a kwarg, not within your string.

Comment: using 'data={"key":"value"}' or '{"key":"value"}' return the same result 400 on curl is pass .?

Comment: Use `data={"key":"value"}` not `data = '{"key":"value"}'`. You've to use a dictionary, not a string.